# SQL - Read an XML node from a table field

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a field called `RequestParameters` in one of my SQL table called `Requests` with XML data. An example would be:

```
<RequestParameters xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Name.Space" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="1">
  <Data z:Id="2" i:type="CheckoutRequest">
    <UserGuid>7ec38c44-5aa6-49e6-9fc7-25e9028f2148</UserGuid>
    <DefaultData i:nil="true" />
  </Data>
</RequestParameters>
```

I ultimately want to retrieve the value of UserGuid. For that, I am doing this:

```
SELECT RequestParameters.value('(/RequestParameters/Data/UserGuid)[0]', 'uniqueidentifier') as UserGuid
FROM Requests
```

However, the results I am seeing are all `NULL`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the default namespace and use `[1]` instead of `[0]`.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(default 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Name.Space')
SELECT RequestParameters.value('(/RequestParameters/Data/UserGuid)[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') as UserGuid
FROM Requests;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79647/2)

Comment: yup , specifying nanespace is necessary . +1

Comment: @Noobie `[1]` is used to specify the first instance of the value you want. You could use `[2]` to get the second instance if you had more than one `UserGuid` in your XML. `[0]` specifies the value *before* the first and well.. there is nothing before the first so you get nothing back.

Answer (score -1):

```
  declare @XML xml

  set @XML = "<RequestParameters       xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Name.Space"       xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="1">
    <Data z:Id="2" i:type="CheckoutRequest">
      <UserGuid>7ec38c44-5aa6-49e6-9fc7-25e9028f2148</UserGuid>
      <DefaultData i:nil="true" />
    </Data>
  </RequestParameters>"

 select @XML.value('(/RequestParameters/Data /UserGuid)[1]', 'varchar')
  '
```

Comment: It could be because this answer does not work. Have you tried it? If not you could test it [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13179)